# Unsupported Macbook 4,1 (2008) on 10.10.5 (Supplementary) - No Audio After Update - What Next?

Tags: macos, audio, software-update, kernel-extensions

*NOTE: If you are not interested in how I got to this point, skip to the last paragraph.*

As it currently stands, I have Mac OS X Yosemite running on my black Macbook 4,1. With the following kexts (in addition to the defaults provided by MacPostFactor), I was able to get OS X 10.10.2 running fully, with little-to-no issues:

- Intel GMA X3100 kexts (provided via an installer)
- IOAudioFamily.kext
- AppleHDA.kext
- Apple_iSight.kext

I also installed the NoSleep extension, the Software Update Patcher (not before learning the hard way), the AirDrop Enabler, and the System Font extension (which changes the system font to the one used by the Apple Watch). In order to enable the kexts, I had to pull up KextDropper and enter this in the Terminal:

- sudo nvram boot-args= kext-dev-mode=1

Everything (including Time Machine :) worked fine without modification after the update to 10.10.2 - except for the fact that I can't change the screen brightness (battery killer status confirmed).

However, I did mention: "not before learning the hard way"...
In order to get to this version number, I had to update from 10.10.0, and when I did that update, I did it without the Software Update patcher. So, I ended up going into the Recovery Image, and deleting 'PlatformSupport.plist' from the Terminal (fun times?). Then, I rebooted into the fully-functioning 10.10.5 (Revision 1) OS X desktop. This, of course, was the easy part. I have now encountered the difficult part.

What I am here to ask about is something that occurred after my update to 10.10.5, Revision 2. When I updated to 10.10.5 (Revision 2 - *Recovery Update*), everything continued to work, except for one thing - the Macbook is now back to having no audio support. I checked the boot arguments, and that revealed nothing. The kexts I installed are still in '/System/Library/Extensions'. I don't know what happened.

The main question(s):

1) ***How can I get audio capabilities back for this version of OS X?***

2) ***Should I simply update to El Capitan (from App Store update) instead?***

**Possibly related (but not identical in nature):**

- ["Apple Stack Xchange | Installing Yosemite on Unsupported Macbook 4,1"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136834/install-mavericks-on-unsupported-macbook-4-1)
- ["MacRumors | Post by AtVusr, on Installing Yosemite on Unsupported Macbooks"](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/os-x-yosemite-on-unsupported-macs-guide.1761432/#post-19436309)
- ["MacRumors | Post by a02, on Installing Yosemite on Unsupported Macbooks"](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/os-x-yosemite-on-unsupported-macs-guide.1761432/page-5#post-20072806)

The last link was one of the first solutions I tested - Voodoo audio kext(s) weren't able to fix this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I've the solution.
Download this audio kext.
Drag the two files AppleHDA.kext and IOAudioFamily.kext into the kext utility.app
After all is ok you can reboot and it works :-)

Link : https://mega.nz/#!9hcgFKRK

Comment: From where do the kexts originate? I did a similar kext-replacement operation to get the audio working for 10.10.3.

Comment: From Mavericks I think

Comment: What version number are the kexts ("Get Info" - Finder)?

Comment: Hey - I made it back to 10.10.5 - the Combo Update. Besides being unable to play Minecraft anymore (OpenGL?), everything else works. Still can't change the screen brightness, but that's minor. Are your kexts version 2.1.3, from OS X 10.9 Mavericks for the Mac Pro/XServe?

Comment: I updated my kexts again, using a download from a MacPro/XServ system. They work pretty well, but I'm still on the fence about attempting the Recovery Update...

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I'm attempting the Recovery/Security update again today, to see if I can get Audio working for 10.10.5 latest. Could you allow access to the kexts please?

Comment: The link is broken :(

Answer (score -1):

I have the same computer, there is no hw acceleration for the gma x3100 drivers you are using. Check the console, you’ll find OpenGL is being turned off. Chrome won’t work, launchpad is terribly slow, youtube doesn’t work etc.

Re audio try applehda patcher by mirone

Comment: We were discussing the lack of audio - not graphics acceleration. This answer is unrelated to the original issue. Please re-read the OP and edit your answer to address the issue.